# How to programmatically find if a Windows desktop app is being used on a Windows handheld device

Tags: c#, windows

I have a Windows desktop app in C#. I need to estimate how many users are using it on a handheld device - mainly a tablet like Lenovo Yoga tablet or SurfacePro.

I've found answers about using a web browser request which I cannot do as this is a desktop app.

I need an approach to identify if the app is being used on a handheld device.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Windows desktop app in C#. I need to estimate how many users
>   are using it on a handheld device - mainly a tablet like Lenovo Yoga
>   tablet or SurfacePro.

If you only want the estimate, i think a better approach would be using google analytics, it can be used with windows apps too [Google Analytics for Windows apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238405.aspx)

> I need an approach to identify if the app is being used on a handheld
>   device.

If you need to identify the type of device for some functionality, what you need to do is identify the device family.

Answer (score 0):

if you're creating a uwp app, you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIViewSettings#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_UIViewSettings_UserInteractionMode):

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
  public MainPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    // Every view gets an initial SizeChanged, so we will do all our 
    // work there. This means that our view also responds to dynamic
    // changes in user interaction mode.
    Window.Current.SizeChanged += SizeChanged;
  }

  private void SizeChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    switch(UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode)
    {
      case UserInteractionMode.Mouse:
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "MouseLayout", true);
        break;

      case UserInteractionMode.Touch:
      default:
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "TouchLayout", true);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```